# django "only()" method seems not to work properly

Tags: python, django

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    click = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
```

Below, what I coded

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=3).only('name')
print(post.values())
```

Result what I expected

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Micheal'}]>
```

But the actual result was

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Micheal', 'click': 2, 'content': 'asdf'}]>
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've misunderstood the usage of [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only):

> The only() method is more or less the opposite of defer(). You call it
>   with the fields that should not be deferred when retrieving a model.
>   If you have a model where almost all the fields need to be deferred,
>   using only() to specify the complementary set of fields can result in
>   simpler code.

What is you're looking for is [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) and [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
Post.objects.filter(id=3).values('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=3).only('name')
print(post.values())
```

We can write your query in one line like:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=3).only('name').values()
print(post)
```

---

**In [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values), if you don’t specify the fields, each dictionary will contain a key and value for `every field in the database table`.**

> The values() method takes optional positional arguments, *fields, which specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited. If you specify the fields, each dictionary will contain only the field keys/values for the fields you specify. If you don’t specify the fields, each dictionary will contain a key and value for every field in the database table.

---

So, that is why:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Micheal', 'click': 2, 'content': 'asdf'}]>
```

Is the expected output.

---

> How can I fix the problem?

- Just user [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).
- You might be interested in using the `flat=True` argument of `values_list()` as you want only one field (`name`).